# Is it possible for one NavLink to give an active class for 2 pages?

Tags: reactjs, url, navigation, react-router, url-parameters

I have this code:

```
    <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
      <NavLink exact={true} to="/admin" activeClassName="activeClass">
        <ListGroupItem>
          <Fa icon="money" className="mr-3"/>
          Orders
        </ListGroupItem>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/admin/booths" activeClassName="activeClass">
        <ListGroupItem>
          <Fa icon="camera" className="mr-3"/>
          Booths
        </ListGroupItem>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/admin/components" activeClassName="activeClass">
        <ListGroupItem>
          <Fa icon="cubes" className="mr-3"/>
          Components
        </ListGroupItem>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to={`/admin/schedule/starting_ship_date=${start}&ending_ship_date=${end}`} activeClassName="activeClass">
        <ListGroupItem>
          <Fa icon="calendar" className="mr-3"/>
          Schedule
        </ListGroupItem>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/admin/lateReturns" activeClassName="activeClass">
        <ListGroupItem>
          <Fa icon="exclamation" className="mr-3"/>
          Late Returns
        </ListGroupItem>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/admin/allInbound" activeClassName="activeClass">
        <ListGroupItem>
          <Fa icon="clock-o" className="mr-3"/>
          All Inbound
        </ListGroupItem>
      </NavLink>
    </ListGroup>
```

I want to make it so that the first NavLink (the one that goes to `'/admin'`) will not only be active for the `/admin` page, but it will also be active for the `/admin/orders` page and the `/admin/orders/orderid:id` page. Is something like this possible and if so how would I go about doing it?

Comment: I guess `NavLink` comes from a 3rd-party lib?

Comment: No `NavLink` comes from `react-router-dom`. The `ListGroup` and `ListGroupItem`'s come from `mdbreact` though.

Comment: ...that is a 3rd-party lib (not react-core I mean) :)

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md#isactive-func - you can supply your own logic for that - but it may conflict with the `exact` you have on /admin - you can first try removing this.

Comment: Thank you Dimitar. With that I was able to figure it out.

Comment: @NathanGeckle can I know how you work on this issue? Thank you